# Escape with Unicode Code Points similar to PHP in Javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode, character-encoding

When using PHP to generate JSON, it encodes higher characters using the \u0123 code-point notation.

(I *know* this not necessary, but for unnamed reasons I want that.)

I am trying to achieve the same in JavaScript. I searched high and low and found nothing. The encodeUri function does nothing for me (even though many suggested that it would).

Any helpful hints? I hope that I do not have to use some big external library but rather something build-in or a few lines of nice code - this can not be this hard, can it...?!

I have an input string in the form of:

```
var stringVar = 'Hällö Würld.';
```

My desired conversion would give me something like:

```
var resultStringVar = 'H\u00e4ll\u00f6 W\u00fcrld.';
```

Comment: I added an example of what I expect to achieve. It now has a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve made a library for just that called [*jsesc*](http://mths.be/jsesc). From its README:

> This is a JavaScript library for [escaping JavaScript strings](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) while generating the shortest possible valid ASCII-only output. [Here’s an online demo.](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes)
>
> This can be used to avoid [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) and other encoding issues, or even to [avoid errors](https://twitter.com/annevk/status/380000829643571200) when passing JSON-formatted data (which may contain U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR, U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR, or [lone surrogates](http://esdiscuss.org/topic/code-points-vs-unicode-scalar-values#content-14)) to a JavaScript parser or an UTF-8 encoder, respectively.

For your specific example, use it as follows:

```
var stringVar = 'Hällö Würld.';
var resultStringVar = jsesc(stringVar, { 'json': true, 'wrap': false });
```

Comment: Funny, while doing my research, all I could find were your sites :D I found them quite informative, but I dont think I need the whole library - what functions do you use internally? Or is there too much going on?

Comment: @ThE_-_BliZZarD There’s a link to the source code in my answer. Check it out – it should be fairly straightforward. The main loop, where it loops through the string and escapes each character as needed, is here: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc/blob/a4368cc02063500fedd3fbae99c8042a086a4e8b/jsesc.js#L161-L186